# libcurl work perfect on ubuntu virtual machine but can not resolve host on windows

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, libcurl

how it can be that in windows visual studio 2013 curl_easy_perform returns cannot_resolve host but same code in same pc works fine in ubuntu virtual machine ?

```
CURL *curl;
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_SSL);
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://myhost.com/api/login/");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
// calculate request header
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"username\":\"name\", \"password\":\"test\"}" );
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback); // set callback

curl_easy_perform(curl); // perform request
curl_easy_cleanup(curl); // cleanup request
return 0;
```

the verbose output of programm is following

```
> * STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x907ef0; line 1034 (connection #-5000)
> * Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
> * STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x907ef0; line 1071 (connection #0)
> * Could not resolve host: myhost.com
> * Closing connection 0
> * The cache now contains 0 members
> * Expire cleared
```

Comment: Is `myhost.com` in your host file on the Ubuntu machine? Also make sure the Windows machine can resolve your host outside of curl (i.e. with ping)

Comment: did you try a different url?

Comment: no myhost.com is outside of my computer and i've tryed other hosts google.com , example.com ... and ping can resolve myhost.com

Comment: does your curl installation contain SSL support?

Comment: yes, it's contain SSl support

Comment: As mentioned above, did you try resolving hostnames using other clients, such as ping, or nslookup?
Did you try taking a capture on port 53 to see if there are any DNS queries coming out from your Windows setup?

Comment: yes ping can resolve. what regards to capture port 53 , unfortunately i do not know what it's means.

Comment: Try setting the `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` option to `CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4`; there's too much that could potentially be going on here.

Comment: I've tried, and it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i find out the solution.
the problem was in curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_SSL); function call.
when i change it to curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);  the program starts work as expected.